Декораторы python. Обращения между файлами
Школьный вопрос. Есть два файла, например main.py и decorator.py. В файле main.py есть функции, которые мы обёртываем декораторами из decorator.py, а в декораторе вызываем другую функцию из этого же main.py. Соответственно, в main.py мы импортируем decorator.py. Как мне получить в decorator.py функции из main.py?

Вынести используемую в декораторе функцию в отельный модуль, например. Либо передавать ее внутрь как параметр декоратора.

Спасибо. Выведу в отдельный модуль.
